# Method used by similar classes

Tags: object

I have to design three separate classes which have very similar attributes and use the same methods (not by choice - it's the assignment. My question is, how does one make a function which can be called by three classes (all in the same header file)?

Specifically - If I design a template which will take care of each method, how do I make it accessible to each method? Could somebody point me to a similar example?

Comment: You may use singleton design pattern......Do you know about that?

Comment: No, I don't believe I have heard that term. Do you have some documentation or something I could further look at?

Comment: Make a fourth class with all the common attributes, extend it in rest three.